# Course schedule to Add,view,update and delete a record

Tags: java

I have a .txt file and I want it to read the contents of that file for an add record option function, however I get this error when running it:

> The system cannot find the file specified

```
package mylib1;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.Scanner;


    import java.io.*;

    public class Schedule {

        public static void executeTask(int option){
            char addmore='n'; 
            switch(option){
            case 0: 
                    return; 
            case 1: 
                    do{
                        add();
                        addmore = getContinue("add");
                        if(addmore=='n')
                            break;
                    }while(true); 
                    break;
            case 2: 
                do{
                    view();
                    addmore = getContinue("view");
                    if(addmore=='n')
                        break;
                }while(true); 
                break;
            }
        }
         public static char getContinue(String methodName){
             char ch='n'; 
             try{
                    System.out.println("Do you want to " +methodName + " more records (y/n)?"); 
                    ch = (char) System.in.read();

                }catch(IOException e){
                    System.out.println("IOException in input....");
                }
             return ch;
         }
        public static void add() {
            char ch; 
            System.out.println("Add Record");
            System.out.println("---------------");
            System.out.println();
            File file = new File("readcoursefile.txt");

                try {

                    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

                    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                        String line = scanner.nextLine();
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                    scanner.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println("file not found");
                }

            try{
                System.out.println("Do you want to save/cancel record s/c"); 
                ch = (char) System.in.read();

            }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("IOException in input....");
            }



        }

        public static void update(){
            System.out.println("Update Record");
            System.out.println("---------------");
            System.out.println();


        }

        public static void view(){
            System.out.println("View Record");
            System.out.println("---------------");
            System.out.println();



        }

        public static void delete(){
            System.out.println("Delete Record");
            System.out.println("---------------");
            System.out.println();

            //prompt user for console input (attributes)

            //write/update user record from file.

        }

        public static void search(){
            System.out.println("Search Record");
            System.out.println("---------------");
            System.out.println();



        }



    }
```

Comment: looks like file is not present where system looks, please put file into proper place, or provide full path of file. so that system can find it easily

Answer (score 1):

You're not specifying a full path for the text file on this line:

```
File file = new File("readcoursefile.txt");
```

So your program will search for the file in a list of places, starting with the [*working* directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) of the application (which is nearly always the same folder as the compiled application.

This could be a /debug or similar place if you're using an IDE.

You can check what this *working* directory is with a line similar to the following:

```
String curDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

And you can change the directory as follows:

```
System.setProperty("user.dir", "/tmp");
```

.
You have four options really:

1. Hardcode a full path (eg: `File file = new File("c:\coursefiles\readcoursefile.txt");`
2. Add a configuration file variable for the file location.
3. Prompt the user to specify the path for the file.
4. Continue to use relative paths and ensure the file is placed within it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working well.You just provide the proper path as @Sk93 suggested

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


import java.io.*;

public class Schedule {
public static void executeTask(int option){
System.out.println("i am in executeTask");
            char addmore='n'; 
            switch(option){
            case 0: 
                    return; 
            case 1: 
                    do{
                        add();
                        addmore = getContinue("add");
                        if(addmore=='n')
                            break;
                    }while(true); 
                    break;
case 2: 
                do{
                    view();
                    addmore = getContinue("view");
                    if(addmore=='n')
                        break;
                }while(true); 
                break;
            }
        }
         public static char getContinue(String methodName){
             char ch='n'; 
             try{
                    System.out.println("Do you want to " +methodName + " more records (y/n)?"); 
                    ch = (char) System.in.read();

                }catch(IOException e){
                    System.out.println("IOException in input....");
                }
             return ch;
         }
        public static void add() {
            char ch; 
            System.out.println("Add Record");
            System.out.println("---------------");
            System.out.println();
            File file = new File("readcoursefile.txt");//Here you need to provide proper path.You just go to your file location and copy the path and paste here

                try {

                    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

                    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                        String line = scanner.nextLine();
                        System.out.println(line);
                    }
                    scanner.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println("file not found");
                }

            try{
                System.out.println("Do you want to save/cancel record s/c"); 
                ch = (char) System.in.read();

            }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("IOException in input....");
            }



        }

        public static void update(){
            System.out.println("Update Record");
            System.out.println("---------------");
            System.out.println();


        }

        public static void view(){
            System.out.println("View Record");
            System.out.println("---------------");
            System.out.println();



        }

        public static void delete(){
            System.out.println("Delete Record");
            System.out.println("---------------");
            System.out.println();

            //prompt user for console input (attributes)

            //write/update user record from file.

        }

        public static void search(){
            System.out.println("Search Record");
            System.out.println("---------------");
            System.out.println();



        }

public static void main(String []args)
{
Schedule sh=new Schedule();
System.out.println("i am in main");
sh.executeTask(1);
}


    }
```

Comment: CID          Course Name          Short Name
  1   Fundamentals of Programming  FOP
i want to add this record in the output but i am having problems writing code for this.